# The result of the following set expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please explain the following expression to me and what is the result set?

$$ (\{2i \;\vert\; i \in \mathbb{N} \} \cap \{p \;\vert\; p \text{ is a prime number } \} ) \setminus \{z \in \mathbb{Z} \;\vert\; z \le 0 \} $$

Comment: The person who wrote that needs a $\LaTeX$ course. Anyway, this set, as I understand it, is (read from left to right, it will make sense), the intersection of the positive even numbers and the set of prime numbers, minus the negative numbers.

Comment: The backslash means set minus, i.e. remove nonpositive integers from the first part of the set expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A:=\{2i \mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ is the set of all even natural numbers.
$B:=\{p \mid p\textrm{ is a prime number}\}$ is the set of all prime numbers.

So $A\cap B$ is the set of all numbers that are in both $A$ and $B$, i.e. all numbers that are even, natural, and prime, so $A\cap B=\{2\}$.

$C:=\{z\in\mathbb Z\mid z\le 0\}$ is the set of non-positive integers.

$(A\cap B)\setminus C$ is the set of all numbers that are in $A$ and $B$, but not $C$, i.e. all numbers that are natural, even, prime, and non-negative, which again is $\{2\}$.